# Using control functions in a bitmap in C#

Tags: c#

I was thinking of implementing a bitmap into a picturebox (or the otherway round), such that I could have the option to:
1.drag and drop the item (Control function with mousebuttons)
2.rotate the item (bitmap function).
This is what I have currently:

`Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"my source");`
`PictureBox item = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();`
I create the picturebox on the click of a button:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        item.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        item.Location = new Point(400, 200);
        item.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseDown);
        item.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseMove);
        item.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseUp);
        item.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseWheel);
        item.Image = bmp; 
        item.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.Controls.Add(item); 
        item.BringToFront();

    }
```

and in the textbox_MouseMove void, I try to use the middle button to signal the rotation of the image

```
  void textbox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)        
{

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle ) 
        {

            if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender) 
            {
                return;
            }

            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(objectrotation_Paint); 

            Invalidate();

        }
}
```

where the PaintEvent is responsible for the rotation of the image

```
  private void objectrotation_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs d)

    {

        int dpi = 96;

        bmp.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);

        if (bmp != null)
        {
            float bw2 = bmp.Width / 2f;    
            float bh2 = bmp.Height / 2f;   

            d.Graphics.TranslateTransform(bw2, bh2);
            d.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
            d.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-bw2, -bh2);

            d.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,0,0);

            d.Graphics.ResetTransform();
        }

    }
```

This however would create two sets of images, i.e. when I press button 2 I get one image, when I move my mouse with middle button down I get the second image (rotating).Refering to some of the questions on here, people recommend using
`item.Image = bmp;`
but it simply copies the from picturebox to the bitmap while they have seperate controls. While the picturebox class could not perform rotations without implementing a Bitmap, the Bitmap class does not have the option to perform actions like `OnMouseMove` etc.

Is there any way to combine my bitmap and the picturebox such that I could achieve my two goals?

Comment: Use : pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip()

Comment: Sounds like you have no idea what the players' role are. A PictureBox can display a Bitmap and is responsible for all user interaction.  A PictureBox is a control. A Bitmap is not. A Bitmap is a grid of colored pixels which can be manipulated in various ways. You change a Bitmap and replace the PictureBox's Image by the new version.

Comment: Following your advice, now I have a line `item.Image = bmp;` right after the transformation to replace the old one, however I still get 2 images (one fixed one rotating), any idea why?

Comment: @TaW forgot the tag my bad

Comment: Well, a `PictureBox` is mighty beast. It can display __three__ bitmaps at once: __One__ in the `BackgroundImage`, which you don't use. __One__ in the `Image` and __one__ on its surface, painted there in the `Paint` event. If you simply want to modify the `Image` you do __not__ need need the `Paint` event. Simply modify the `Image` bitmap and assign it back to the `Image` ! - So write a function for the rotation: `Bitmap rotate(bitmap bmp, float, angle)` instead of the Paint code. Make sure to keep the original around and always use it for the rotation, or else the quality will degrade!

Comment: Also: Do not add event handler mulitple times or else the event will be calles ever so often.  - You also metion Drag&Drop, but that is not really part of the question, right?

Comment: @TaW Thank you so much with your advice, now it's working! The drag and drop was not the issue as I could do it via picturebox controls. I am now using the graphics control `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` instead of the paint event and it's working wonders